# Can every connected reductive group over a char $p$ field be defined over $\mathbb F_p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

If I have a connected reductive group $G$ over a field with characteristic $p>0$, can it always be defined over $\mathbb F_p$? For split groups like $GL_n, GSp_{2n}$ it's trivial, how about general case?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer is "yes", since such a reductive group arises via a sesisimple group which in turn is determined by its root datum. And given any root datum, one can construct a semisimple algebraic group over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with that root datum. I guess the only potential issue is when one goes to the reductive group via a quotient of a product with a torus, and whether this still all works over the prime field.

Comment: For more detail, see for example II.1.17 in Jantzen's book as well as the references he gives there.

Comment: Good question. I think one should be able to find most of the necessary details in Jantzen plus references, but I have not really thought about this.

Comment: As @TobiasKildetoft points out, the answer is certainly yes if you assume that $G$ is split. Every split group has a unique split model over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ in fact (the so-called Chevalley group).

Comment: Also, just to point out, the example I gave below is for groups over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Over any separably closed field every group is split, in which case it does have a model (usually MANY models) over its prime subfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Here's a simple example. Let $T:=\mathsf{Res}^1_{\mathbb{F}_{p^4}/\mathbb{F}_{p^2}}\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{F}_{p^4}}$. Then, $T$ is a non-split one-dimensional torus over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ which does not have a model over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Indeed, to say that $T$ has a model over $\mathbb{F}_p$ would mean that there was some torus $T'$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $T'_{\mathbb{F}_{p^2}}\cong T$. But evidently $\dim T'=1$ and, up to isomorphism, the only one-dimensional tori over $\mathbb{F}_p$ are $\mathsf{Res}^1_{\mathbb{F}_{p^2}/\mathbb{F}_p}\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{F}_{p^2}}$ and $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{F}_p}$. Both of these split over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ so can't be models of $T$.

**EDIT:** To be clear, I was answering the question in the first sentence of the body of the post. The answer to the question in the title is yes, as **Tobias Kildetoft** pointed out in the above comments. Every group over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is split, and every split group has a model over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thank you! That is a good one，using the equivalence of category between torus and integral representations.